# How to create a fully customized Alert Dialog?

Tags: android, layout, customization, android-alertdialog, border

Is there a solution to create an `Alert Dialog` with no borders around? If I create a layout and attach it to the `Alert Dialog`, I have my layout shown, but it's surrounded by the default dialog borders. Any way to cut them off? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create activity and set theme of that activity to dialog

Comment: I bet you can't go any more CUSTOMIZABLE than that! @Dharmendra

Comment: @Dharmendra, It doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one [way](http://blog.androgames.net/10/custom-android-dialog/) (if you don't like this particular example with the green border, scroll below to see a second one I found).

[image] [image]

Here is another [example](http://y-anz-m.blogspot.com/2010/12/androidalertdialog.html) (this one gives you an example without a border, and one with a border. The explanations are in Japanese, but the code is given for both.)

[image: alert dialog with border] [image]

Comment: Top link is broken now.  Better to put in code than links to code, which rarely survive as long as the posting itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
Hi if you use your own layout then set this in your styles.xml

<style name="Theme.Transparent_layout" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>

</style>

and set this style in your manifest file

<activity android:name=".Main" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent_layout" />
```